# JavaScript Stop loading on href

Tags: javascript

I want to redirect a user using `window.location.href` and I want to stop it at anytime.

I tried:

```
window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com"; //Redirect
window.location.href = ""; //Stop Redirecting
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the use case?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. But also, the other server may respond very quickly, like in < 50 miliseconds. There may be no time to do anything meaningful anyway.

Comment: This could mean that you need to restructure your application. If there is a reason to cancel a web request, then you probably want to perform your action using Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Once you redirect the user to the new page, any scripts currently running will be stopped. Thus you cannot "stop" a redirect once you've committed to it.